# How do i upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS or greater?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

When I press upgrade button on upgrade center it starts downloading and suddenly stops and shows message stating authentication failed and advises to check network connection even if it is connected. please help me out of this problem.

Comment: could you gives the complete error report ? use paste bin and give us the link .

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you currently using? To upgrade to 12.04, you should first upgrade to 11.10.

Answer (score 0):

Install update-manager-core if it is not already installed by using terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
```

Launch the upgrade tool:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Follow the on-screen instructions.

Comment: the message is " Authentication failed

Authenticating the upgrade failed. There may be a problem with the network or with the server. " n i m using Ubuntu 10.